# apt-key deprecated 20.10

Tags: apt, 20.10

I am attempting to install pgAdmin4 on 20.10

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

When I do the first step:

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

I get this message:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

Moving to the second step:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

I get this message:

````
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/groovy pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```
````

I have encountered this issue with two or three other public repositories recently. At first I thought it was just a problem with the repository, but I'm beginning to think otherwise.

Comment: The question is totally unclear. `apt-key` is not deprecated. What is "step one" you are stuck at?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man8/apt-key.8.html

attempting to install (ex: curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add) results in the error: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))

Comment: It still works, so I don't see any real problem.

Comment: It's not working though, it's not adding the key.

Maybe I'm completely mixed up, but attempting to go to the next step then results in the error: E: The repository does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: This message is unrelated to the key.

Comment: So that message is because they're not supporting 20.10 yet? Please forgive my obvious cluelessness. I've been using Ubuntu for a few months now and had not encountered this. This error really did not scream 'your release is not supported' to me. I assumed it was related to the deprecation notice.

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: In a browser I can see the releases it supports (in any manner), ie. https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/ taken from your messages...  no *groovy* is present.

Comment: @Pilot6 not sure if you looked recently, but "man apt-key", and at the top it says "apt-key - Deprecated APT key management utility" .. It will also print deprecated in many places. So to those coming here thinking it's not after reading that, it is now. :)